# Mellin transform Gaussian

Tags: calculus, probability

Is there a known formula for the Mellin transform 
$$M(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}\, dx$$
of the Gaussian probability density function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac 12\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}$$

???

If the answer is yes, I would like to see a proof ;-)

Comment: Why are you asking this question? I can't think of any context where this would be relevant. To begin with: the  Mellin transform is defined on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$, while, to be a probability density function, the Gaussian must be defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, the Mellin transform is related to the multiplicative structure on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$, while the Gaussians are more related to the additive structure on $\mathbb{R}$. [continued]

Comment: ... So, you can probably look e.g. at log-Gaussians, are or at the Mellin transform of functions such as $e^{-x^2}$. But I am curious: in what context would you legitimately look at the Mellin transform of a Gaussian probability density?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Mellin transform is a usefull tool for studying the distribution of a product of independent random variables. Of course, it is defined just on the positive halfline, but you can decompose a random Variable X in their positive and their negative part. So it makes sense to study the Mellin transform of pdf's of random variables like e.g. the gaussian. It is also well known (and quite easy to prove), that the Mellin transform of a standard-gaussian-rv is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}2^{\frac 12(s-3)}\Gamma\left(\frac s2\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

I just asked maple this question, and maple answered: (here $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal density)
$$
   \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \phi(x)\; dx = \frac{2^{-3/2+s/2}\Gamma(s/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}
$$
(which coincides with answer already given in comments)

Answer (score 0):

For $\Re(s)>0$ with $y=x^2$
$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty y^{s/2-1}e^{-y}dy=\frac12 \Gamma(s/2)$$
Then
$$\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-(x-a)^2}dx= e^{-a^2}\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(2a)^k}{k!} \frac12 \Gamma((s+k)/2)$$ is some kind of hypergeometric function